# Cannot change language in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I have got a problem with my Laravel application - I am not able to change my app language and keep it set. After the next request to the server it goes back to default language set. The only thing which is possible is to change the default language in app.php file. I have recently updated my app to Laravel 5.22 - could it be connected with the problem mentioned above?

Would you have some kind of advice on this?

Thank you in advance for any kind of help

Answer (score 0):

in you route group  each time load the language

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Language'], function () {
        require (__DIR__ . '/Routes/Language/Language.php');
    });
```

in language.php(i have loaded in different route directory )

```
Route::get('lang/{lang}', 'LanguageController@swap');
```

in LaunguageController store in session to persist the selection

```
class LanguageController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param $lang
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function swap($lang)
    {
        session()->put('locale', $lang);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```